# Weird behaviour of a generator function while converting it to a list

Tags: python, list, generator

I am trying to get **every state of a list** while it is being **sorted** for a visualization.
So with **bubbleSort algorithm**

i made a **generator function** :

```
def bubbleSort(arr): 

    n = len(arr)

    yield arr  # yielding original state

    for i in range(n):

        swapped = False
        
        for j in range(0, n-i-1): 
        
            if arr[j] > arr[j+1]:
                arr[j], arr[j+1] = arr[j+1], arr[j]
                swapped = True

                yield arr   # yielding every state during bubbleSort
                
        if (swapped == False):
            break

arr = [64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90]

generator=bubbleSort(arr)

for i in generator:
    print(i)
```

Now this **gives** me my **desired output**.

```
[64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90]
[34, 64, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90]       
[34, 25, 64, 12, 22, 11, 90]
[34, 25, 12, 64, 22, 11, 90]
[34, 25, 12, 22, 64, 11, 90]
[34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 64, 90]
[25, 34, 12, 22, 11, 64, 90]
[25, 12, 34, 22, 11, 64, 90]
[25, 12, 22, 34, 11, 64, 90]
[25, 12, 22, 11, 34, 64, 90]
[12, 25, 22, 11, 34, 64, 90]
[12, 22, 25, 11, 34, 64, 90]
[12, 22, 11, 25, 34, 64, 90]
[12, 11, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90]
[11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90]
```

But if i **convert it to a list** using any of these ways: (One at a time)

```
#1
print(list(generator))

#2
l=[i for i in generator] 
print(l)

#3
l=[]
for i in generator:    
    l.append(i)
print(l)

#4
l=[*generator]
print(l)
```

It will give me o/p as below : (**all states** are **already sorted** or last states)

```
[[11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90]]
```

Now i don't understand why this happens but , this gets even more confusing for me when i do
**any of these** and it **gives me the desired o/p**.

```
#1
l=[list(i) for i in generator]  #list(i)
print(l)

#2
l=[i.copy() for i in generator]  #i.copy()
print(l)

#3
l=[]
for i in generator: 
    l.append(list(i))  #list(i)
print(l)

#4
l=[]
for i in generator:
    l.append(i.copy()) #i.copy()
print(l)
```

**o/p**:

```
[[64, 34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90], [34, 64, 25, 12, 22, 11, 90], [34, 25, 64, 12, 22, 11, 90], [34, 25, 12, 64, 22, 11, 90], [34, 25, 12, 22, 64, 11, 90], [34, 25, 12, 22, 11, 64, 90], [25, 34, 12, 22, 11, 64, 90], [25, 12, 34, 22, 11, 64, 90], [25, 12, 22, 34, 11, 64, 90], [25, 12, 22, 11, 34, 64, 90], [12, 25, 22, 11, 34, 64, 90], [12, 22, 25, 11, 34, 64, 90], [12, 22, 11, 25, 34, 64, 90], [12, 11, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90], [11, 12, 22, 25, 34, 64, 90]]
```

Can anyone explain it to me **why** the **difference in outputs** between **last 2 inputs** ?
What changes when i do **i.copy()** or **list(i)** for **every state in the generator** ?
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Your `yield`s always use to the same object as the input (same id as your `arr`). Then you change the contents of the `arr`, but not the id. Compare to how, if you have `test_list = [arr, arr, arr]`, if you try to change the contents of `test_list[2]` (like  `test_list[2] [0] = "something"`), the `test_list[0]` will show the same change. However, `test_list = [arr, arr.copy(), arr.copy()]` has a different behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a single `arr` object that is being mutated inside the generator.

If you print it in between the mutations, you get a snapshot of each individual state, since the current state of `arr` is printed to the console before it changes.

When you capture that `arr` object in a list comprehension, though, you just have a list with a bunch of references to that one object, so as `arr` changes, so too does every entry in your list.

If you wanted to change that, you could `yield arr.copy()` inside your generator to make sure that you're always yielding a unique copy that won't change as the generator continues to iterate.  This would have the same effect that you're seeing when you call `copy()` or `list()` outside of the generator (either of those methods results in a new copy which does not change when `arr` is modified inside the generator).